# Difference between "the meeting is planned..." and "the meeting has planned.."

Tags: meaning, difference

Are these sentences correct?

1. The meeting is planned to be held in the coming days.
2. The meeting has planned to be held in the coming days.

What are the differences between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the first sentence is correct.

The phrase **is planned** is passive voice - meaning that someone unmentioned has planned the meeting.

The phrase **has planned** is active voice - meaning that the subject of the sentence has actively done the planning.  "The meeting **has planned**..." makes no sense because the meeting is not a person who is capable of doing the action of planning.

It might be clearer if we add in the person doing the planning.  Call this person "Maurice".  Adding Maurice to both of your sentences:

1. The meeting is planned **by Maurice** to be held in the coming days.
2. **Maurice** has planned the meeting to be held in the coming days.

Note that in 1. I just had to insert the phrase "by Maurice" but in 2. I had to move around the words "the meeting" in order to make Maurice the subject of the sentence as the person actually doing the planning.